# repairing break in Invisible Fence (TM)

Tags: electric-fence

I'm trying to repair a break (probably 2 of them) in an Inivisible Fence (that actual brand).  Everywhere I look, it says to put a 100uH inductor in parallel with the fence leads at the transmitter.    Then use a portable AM radio to follow the fence line.

The thing is, the transmitter, an ICT801 unit (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1315539/Invisible-Fence-Ict-801.html) operates at either 7 or 10kHz.   Which are of course orders of magnitude different in frequency from the AM radio band.

So, is the AM radio going to detect harmonics of the 7 or 10kHz signal, or is this advice targeted at other similar systems that use different frequencies ?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: Inductor and $12 AM radio on order !   Just curious here ...

Comment: Another rec is to wind a piece of the fence wire around a lawn mower sparkplug - generator some RF white noise I guess.